# Filter sent items based on the recipients email address in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am working on an activity facility which stores incoming and outgoing emails in the database for different contacts. I do this by looping through each folder in my namespace and restricting emails based on the sender email address.

I have managed to store incoming emails so far, but outgoing emails are completely ignored for some reason. I am assuming I am doing the "Mailtiems.Restrict" incorrectly, however I could not figure out what it may be. Please see the code below:

```vb
If folder.Name = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Name Then
    outlookItems = folder.Items
    outlookItems = outlookItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = " & Quote(txtContactPersonalEmailAddress.Text) & " AND [MessageClass] = 'IPM.Note'")
    ' Count total folder items for progress bar
    iOutlookFolderTotalMailItems = outlookItems.Count
```

The count always returns 0 even though I have sent an email to this contact and it appears in my "Sent Items" folder. I wonder if there is a different property I will need to use for "Sent Items" other than "SenderEmailAddress".

Comment: Are you sending to an Exchange recipient? Does txtContactPersonalEmailAddress.Text contain an SMTP address?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I am sending from an Exchange account if that's what you mean. txtContactPersonalEmailAddress.Text contains a string of an ordinary email address such as "thisaddress@gmail.com". At the moment I am just iterating through every email in my sent box (roughly 5000 mail items) to find a matching email and then adding this to the database. Looping through 5000 mailitems take up quite a long time and thus I am trying to use restrict, which in my case is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for the **recipients** rather than the **sender**, you should not be specifying `SenderEmailAddress` - the sender will always be you.

See [Filter sent items outlook by address in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644165/filter-sent-items-outlook-by-address-in-excel-vba)