# Filter sent items outlook by address in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, office-automation

I am hoping to filter the mails in my 'sent items' folder based on the email address of my contact person, i.e. sent to but my attempts so far failed. I am trying to use the filter method in the example below.

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFldr As Object
Dim olItems As Object
Dim emailStr As String
Dim filter As String

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

Debug.Print "olFldr: " & olFldr

emailStr = "sombody@gmail.com" '(email address in Excel spreadsheet)
Debug.Print "emailStr: " & emailStr

Set olItems = olFldr.Items

`for the inbox I used SenderEmailAddress. Attempts with RecipientEmailAddress etc did not work. It would help if I knew how you can see which fields are there to search through, but I don't know how to access this information, nor can I find it on google. 

filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & emailStr & "'"
Set olItems = olFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)

End sub
```

I figured out that the recipient Address is found here:
`olSentFldr.Items.Item(1).Recipients.Item(1).Address`

but this still won't work:

```
Debug.Print olSentFldr.Items.Item(1).Recipients.Item(1).Address filter
= (" Address = """ & emailStr & """") 
Set olSentFldr2 = olSentFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553985/1571407. You have to figure out the `emailStr` for `filter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto" & " Like '" & emailStr & "'`.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model won't let you create a subrestriction on message recipients or attachments.

You can use `To`/`CC`/`BCC` properties in a query, but they correspond to the `PR_DISPLAY_TO`/ `PR_DISPLAY_CC` / `PR_DISPLAY_BCC` MAPI properties and contain a `";"` separated list of recipients and may or may not contain email addresses. Generally, they only contain display names.

Extended MAPI allows to create a subrestriction `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` or `PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS` (create `RES_SUBRESTRICTION` `SRestriction` structure on `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` and `RES_OR` child restriction on `PR_DISPLAY_NAME`, `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS`, `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS`, etc. MAPI properties), but Extended MAPI requires C++ or Delphi.

If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, it supports `RDOFolder.Items.Find/Restrict` queries on message recipients in the form of `"Recipients = 'user@domain.demo'"`

Comment: would it be possible (without making it too complicated) to search for a surname present in the `item.to` string instead with a `Restrict(filter)` approach? Kind of like using `For each Obj in olSentFldr If Instr("surnameX", obj) then... Next` but without using a loop. I tried the loop, but takes a long time to run so I stopped using it immediately again

Comment: Sure, you can do a query like `@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" LIKE '%test%'` (the DASL name corresponds to the `PR_DISPLAY_TO_W` MAPI property).

Comment: But, again, it is not guaranteed to contain the recipient display name. It can be name, address, name + address.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to find any way for searching message recipients, but didn't find any suitable solution.

Comment: Guess I can try to search for both surname and (or) address to make sure I get a hit

Comment: Sure, as long as you are OK with false positives for the recipients with ambiguous names. Emails are by definition unique.