# Filter outlook sent items in vba failing for emails with multiple recipients

Tags: excel, vba, email, filter, outlook

In Excel, i'm attempting to filter sent Items based on recipient email address. For the first part of this challenge see the previous attempt which works if there is 1 recipient in the "TO" section. (see this question: [Filter sent items outlook by address in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644165/filter-sent-items-outlook-by-address-in-excel-vba) for the main code approach).

However, filter 3 below often fails to pick up sent items when there are 2 recipients on the email. The recipient I am filtering for is the 1st address of the 2 recipients in the outlook email.

Any idea how to also grab emails sent that contain the email address of person X in the "TO" but have other recipients as well? And why is it failing to begin with?

```
Sirname = "Smith"
emailStr = "John.Smith@gmail.com"

    filter2 = "@SQL= http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" & " LIKE '%" & SirName & "%'"
    filter3 = "@SQL= http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" & " LIKE '%" & emailStr & "%'"

    Set olSentFldrItems = olSentFldr.Items.Restrict(filter2)
        
    Set olSentFldrItems2 = olSentFldr.Items.Restrict(filter3)
```

this results in olSentFldrItems being empty though sadly in this scenario, and also SirName filter did not pick up this particular email in my sent items.

the suggested answer results in this error

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all guaranteed that an email address will be even present in the `PR_DISPLAY_TO` property - it contains a ";"-separated list of display names (which may or may not include addresses), not SMTP addresses.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), you'd need to create a subrestriction (`RES_SUBRESTRICTION`) on `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` that contains `RES_CONTENT` restriction on `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` / `FL_SUBSTRING | FL_IGNORECASE`.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it creates a recipient subrestriction if you specify `Recipients` (or `To`/`CC`/`BCC`) in a query:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set olSentFldr = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
emailStr = "John.Smith@gmail.com"

filter = "Recipients LIKE '%" & emailStr & "%'"
Set olSentFldrItems = olSentFldr.Items.Restrict(filter)
```

Comment: That filter is Redemption specific - OOM won't let you filter on message recipients or attachments.

Comment: It seems I'm not able to use the redemption option due to IT restrictions at work

Answer (score 0):

You can use *logical operations* to combine several filters in the single search criteria. Common logical operators include `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT`. For example, you may try to combine two filters together using the AND operator:

```
filter = "@SQL= http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" & " LIKE '%" & SirName & "%'" & " AND " & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" & " LIKE '%" & emailStr & "%'"
```

That is not a really good idea to call `Restrict` multiple times with a different search criteria.

Comment: thank for the tip to simplify the code I have. It does however not help find these emails with 2 addresses in the "TO" field

Comment: The filters are separate examples not to be concatenated. Possible confusion due to missing minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You need to set up a string filter correctly to get the right results.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in a comment on a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644165/filter-sent-items-outlook-by-address-in-excel-vba) the trick is figuring out the text for emailStr.

Select mail that should be found.
Use the relevant part of `Debug.Print pa.GetProperty(prop)`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub PropertyAccessor_emailStr()

Dim currItem As Object
Dim pa As propertyAccessor
Dim prop As String

prop = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F"

Set currItem = ActiveExplorer.selection(1)

If currItem.Class = olMail Then
    Debug.Print currItem.subject
    Set pa = currItem.propertyAccessor
    Debug.Print pa.GetProperty(prop)
End If

End Sub
```

I have no knowledge of it but keep in mind the comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71649474/1571407. "...it is not guaranteed to contain the recipient display name. It can be name, address, name + address.".
You may need a concatenated filter.